# Stuck if-statement

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
double weight;
cout<<"Enter the weight of the package \n";
cin>>weight;
if(weight>0.0 || weight<= 1.0){
cout << "The shipping cost is 3.5 Dhs";}
else if (weight>1.0 || weight<=3.0){
    cout << "The shipping cost is 5.5 Dhs";
}
else if(weight>3.0 || weight<=10.0){
    cout << "The shipping cost is 8.5 Dhs";
}
else if (weight>10.0 || weight<=20.0){
    cout << "The shipping cost is 10.5 Dhs";
}
else{
    cout<<"Invalid weight";
}
}
```

Every time I try to enter a different weight it is always stuck in the first condition

Comment: Closely examine `weight > 0.0 || weight <= 1.0`. It's _always true_. If a number isn't greater than 0, then it's less than or equal to 1. Did you mean `&&` instead of `||`?

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply replace "||" with "&&".

weight>0.0 is always true. So the first if block will always result in "true" hence will always print "The shipping cost is 3.5 Dhs".

Tip: when giving a range to check use "&&" instead of "||".

Comment: "Weight > 0.0" isn't always true.

Comment: `weight > 0` is not true if the user enters a negative value.     Also, since (in physics) weight is specified as mass times acceleration i.e. it is a force,   an object can have negative weight *in some reference frame* due to having negative acceleration in that reference frame.

Answer (score 0):

can you think of a number that is neither `> 0.0` nor `< 1.0`?

that's what your if statement is checking for....

As @NathanPierson suggested, you might want to use `&&` instead of `||`

You should get into the habit of "desk checking" your programs; try some sample inputs and think about what will happen:

Examples:

- weight =  -1: that's `<= 1.0`
- weight =   0; that's `<= 1.0`
- weight = 0.5; that's `> 0.0` AND `<= 1.0`
- weight = 1.0; that's `> 0.0` AND `<= 1.0`
- weight = 2.0; that's `> 0.0`